# Python Input Decimal Numbers and Whole Numbers (Float)

Tags: python

I would like to have an input where I can input numbers such as 8 8.5 7 3 4 5.5 8 9 10.5 
and into a list.

I have tried the code below, but:

my input:

Sizes: 9.5 9 10 10.5 3 4 8 7.5

my out put:

[9.5, 9.0, 10.0, 10.5, 3.0, 4.0, 8.0, 7.5]

my desired out put:

[9.5, 9, 10, 10.5, 3, 4, 8, 7.5]

```
select_sizes = [float(x) for x in input('Sizes: ').split()]
print(select_size)
```

i have this list that i have scraped ----- size_ids list : ['91|10.5', '150|9.5', '28|4', '29|5', '22|8', '23|9', '24|10', '25|11', '26|12'] --------- example of inputted list: [5, 5.5, 6, 7, 8.5, 10.5] and basically i want to use the list that i have inputted and if the size_ids list above matches with the first thing in the inputted list, it gets that number in the size_ids list as fsize.

Comment: So you want a mixed list of floats and ints? And when do you want integers? Also what's your input? Strings? Floats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[float(x) if '.' in x else int(x) for x in input('Sizes: ').split()]
```

That's what you want, but it's not ok to mix different types in list, actually you can use floats and it will not brake anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the formatting, you can use a `%g` specifier for printing floats without trailing 0s (it's not a good idea to store a mix of floats and integers):

```
print(", ".join("%g" % x for x in select_size))
```

will print

```
9.5, 9, 10, 10.5, 3, 4, 8, 7.5
```

Of course, you can optionally include square brackets by manually appending them to the resulting string (but do you really need it?)

Comment: i have this list that i have scraped 
-----
size_ids list :

['91|10.5', '150|9.5', '28|4', '29|5', '22|8', '23|9', '24|10', '25|11', '26|12']
---------
example of inputted list:
[5, 5.5, 6, 7, 8.5, 10.5]
and basically i want to use the list that i have inputted and if the size_ids list above matches with the first thing in the inputted list, it gets that number in the size_ids list as fsize.

Comment: @Tony Do you consider, for example, `9` and `9.0` the same or different things?

Comment: they are different things that are scraped.

Comment: @Tony Then you don't need to convert them, you can just store them as strings.

Comment: sorry i meant they are the same things

Comment: @Tony If this, you can store all as floats, then split all your `size_ids` by `|` and perform all the matching (i.e. comparison) on floats. Since integers and floats can be safely compared, this will give you what you need.